# How to enter Text other than english and process the entered text

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have a doubt is it possible to give text other than English  in my latest project I need to support Hindi ,Tamil and French  so if user selects language as Hindi or Tamil or French so what ever value the user is giving in the textbox it must be displayed in the corresponding language selected . My Programming environment is vc++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the String.Globalization classes.

The short answer is that yes it is possible, but you'll need to provide a RESOURCE for every supported language for basically everything (labels, tooltips, and even the values and regexes within the code that will be used to process the entered data).